# How to find directory structure on server asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a webpage on this webpage I need to find the directory name on the server. Can someone explain to me how to does this or better yet show me some source code or reference me to a project with some source code that I can download.

Answer (score 1):

Rick Strahl wrote a great article called [Making Sense of ASP.Net paths](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Dec/21/Making-Sense-of-ASPNET-Paths) that you should definitely read.

Answer (score 0):

The starting directory name of your webpages on the server is

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath
```